# OpenLayer maps uncaught type error cannot read property addlayer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I've been using the example code found here: https://mediarealm.com.au/articles/openstreetmap-openlayers-map-markers/

It says I should be able to call add_map_point at any point within my body, but when I do this I get a error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined
    at add_map_point

I think it is because I am somehow calling it before the map is initialised fully, but I have no idea what the solution for this is.

I have tried moving the `<script>` tags and the JavaScript into the body, however this results in the map not loading at all. If I call the function from like

```
<body onload="initialize_map(); add_map_point(-33.8688, 151.2093);">
```

then it will add a marker as I expect, but calling the function from anywhere else (using `<script>` tags or from within php as I need to do) gives me that error.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Interface-PageStyle.css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
/* OSM & OL example code provided by https://mediarealm.com.au/ */
var map;
var mapLat = 52.626603;
var mapLng = -1.330148;
var mapDefaultZoom = 10;

function initialize_map() {
map = new ol.Map({
target: "map",
layers: [
new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.OSM({
url: "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
})
})
],
view: new ol.View({
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([mapLng, mapLat]),
zoom: mapDefaultZoom
})
});
}

function add_map_point(lat, lng) {
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source:new ol.source.Vector({
features: [new ol.Feature({
geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
})]
}),
style: new ol.style.Style({
image: new ol.style.Icon({
anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
anchorXUnits: "fraction",
anchorYUnits: "fraction",
src: "iconfinder_map-marker_299087.svg"
//Marker icon located at: https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/299087/map_marker_icon, with license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/, no changes made.
})
})
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer); //This line is the problem
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize_map();">

<div id="map" class="mapdiv"></div>
<?php include 'accdatab.php'; 
$volID = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM jobs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $lat = $row['Latitude'];
        $lon = $row['Longitude'];
        //echo "<script> add_map_point(0, 0); </script>";
    }
}

?> 
<script> add_map_point(0, 0); </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The onload function is run after the body has loaded, so script inside the body runs first.  Delete the onload and place the initialize_map(); in a script inside the body.

Comment: @Mike Wow thankyou so much. I never knew about that. It works now! :D